# I wonder why are ... vs i wonder why the majority of people who .... are ...?

Tags: sentence-construction, inversion

Do we say

> I wonder why the majority of people who liked this are ....(adjective)

Or

> I wonder why are the majority of people who liked this ....(adjective)

Answer (score 1):

We say:

> I wonder why the majority of people who liked this are (adjective).

We can also say (although not entirely naturally):

> I wonder: why are the majority of people who liked this (adjective)?

The first one is a statement, and the second one is a question.

`why is [noun] [adjective]` is an independent clause- it can be sentence by itself. On its own, it is also a question.
`why [noun] is [adjective]` is a dependent clause- it *cannot* be sentence by itself.

`I wonder` is an independent clause, so you can add a dependent clause onto the end of it without additional punctuation (as in the first example.)
To combine two independent clauses though, you need additional punctuation. In this instance, because the second clause is a clarification of the first clause, you would use a colon.

Comment: The second example sounds natural to me. It looks a little unusual in written form, but sounds natural when spoken.